# Coping data to different drives using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am backing up our servers and I need to put a couple of encrypted drives offsite, the total size of my backup is 21tb so i need to split it over 1-10tb and 1-12tb.

Is there some code i can run from powershell that will list volume of the disks and split the data onto the 2 drive while keeping the folder structure

Thanks for the noob quesiton

Comment: How about using a dedicated backup software instead? Having a plain directory tree on two different disks with unidentical data could be pretty confusing, unless you have a very good documentation about which files reside on which disk.

Comment: I'd have a look at `robocopy`